# Python populate a docx table with DocxTemplate

Tags: python, docx, templating

I read this documentation on `python-docx-template` but I'm pretty confused on the table section. Let's say I have a docx template called `Template.docx`. Inside the docx file i have a table that only has headers for it's title.

How can I use `python-docx-template` to dynamically populate the table (add rows and values)?

Comment: Do you know the table size?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In general, you unlease the power of `jinja2` with `python-docx-template`.

**Filling individual variables**

Imagine you make a `template.docx` file with a table:

```
**table 1**           **table 2**
{{some_content1}}      {{some_content2}}
```

Then you can fill it using

```
from docxtpl import DocxTemplate
import jinja2

doc = DocxTemplate("template.docx")
context = { 'some_content1' : "test", "some_content_2": "other"}  # Where the magic happens
doc.render(context)
doc.save("generated_doc.docx")
```

If you have the data available as a `pd.DataFrame` then you can also generate the `context` dictionary. For example:

```
import itertools 
context = {}
for row, col in itertools.product(df.index, df.columns):
    context[f'{row}_{col}'] = df.loc[row, col]
```

**Dynamic table**

You can also generate tables dynamically, which I guess you maybe don't want to do (if you are talking about specifying "table headers" in the docx). It's worth looking into though. Use this [template](https://github.com/elapouya/python-docx-template/blob/master/tests/templates/dynamic_table_tpl.docx) with this example from the git tests:

```
from docxtpl import DocxTemplate
tpl = DocxTemplate('templates/dynamic_table_tpl.docx')

context = {
'col_labels' : ['fruit', 'vegetable', 'stone', 'thing'],
'tbl_contents': [
    {'label': 'yellow', 'cols': ['banana', 'capsicum', 'pyrite', 'taxi']},
    {'label': 'red', 'cols': ['apple', 'tomato', 'cinnabar', 'doubledecker']},
    {'label': 'green', 'cols': ['guava', 'cucumber', 'aventurine', 'card']},
    ]
}

tpl.render(context)
tpl.save('output/dynamic_table.docx')
```

Comment: When I create my table inside of docx, I only specify one row for the headers but what is dynamic will be the number of rows I add to the table. So the problem is, I can't create the cells and put the jinja tags in each cell, I'll need to create rows dynamically and add values to these rows. Do you know how I can do that?

Comment: And why can't you specify the headers in python and use the dynamic format? :)

Comment: @Roelant I would reckon if you wanted to style the headers in a certain way then its just easier doing it in the template itself. Im finding it hard adapting the dynamic table example to a normal table use case

Answer (score 4):

You have a working example here (https://chowdera.com/2022/02/202202101239322085.html) with text and images in dynamically populated rows

The template docx file shall have a merged row with the "for" instruction, then a regular row with the desired columns filled with templates, then a merged row with the "endfor" instruction.

```
----------------------------------
| {%tr for f in frameworks %}    |
----------------------------------
| {{ f.title }}  |  {{ f.desc }} |
----------------------------------
| {%tr endfor %}                 |
----------------------------------
```

and the python code :

```
from docxtpl import DocxTemplate
import jinja2

tpl = DocxTemplate('test-tpl.docx')

context = {
    'frameworks': [
        {
            'title': 'this is line # 1',
            'desc': 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.',
        },
        {
            'title': 'this is line # 2',
            'desc': 'Rem nemo ipsam id facilis molestias et enim in pariatur voluptas sed temporibus illo dolor quibusdam.',
        },
        {
            'title': 'this is line # 3',
            'desc': 'A cupiditate esse et dolores temporibus sed sequi nisi cum voluptatem praesentium et odit voluptatem.',
        },
    ],
}
jinja_env = jinja2.Environment(autoescape=True)
tpl.render(context, jinja_env)
tpl.save('test-result.docx')
```

A more complete example (in french) :  https://sysgenre.it/automatisation-de-template-docx/

Comment: Link to a [colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1On8WaSnMAtdY0JqDDmzU-XiW6i6Bz_Tj#scrollTo=nemQU79rSSQY) example