# I've an error when I try to use python-docx-template, script add rows but not the information in a template table

Tags: python, python-3.x, automation, python-docx

Recently I'm using python-docx-template for automate some reports, but I've a problem with tables, so I try to try with a basic table to start and is this table:

[Template table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d9wYo.png)

And I have this code:

```
from docxtpl import DocxTemplate
tpl = DocxTemplate('TITULO.docx')

context = {
'tbl_contents': [
    {'parametro' : 'TEMPERATURA AMBIENTE', 'unidad' : '°C', 'tecnica' : 'TERMOMETRICO', 'metodo' : 'SM 2550 B'},
    {'parametro' : 'TEMPERATURA MUESTRA', 'unidad' : '°C', 'tecnica' : 'TERMOMETRICO', 'metodo' : 'SM 2550 B'},
    {'parametro' : 'pH', 'unidad' : 'UNIDADES', 'tecnica' : 'ELECTROMETRICO', 'metodo' : 'SM 4500H+ B'},
    ]
}

tpl.render(context)
tpl.save('output/dynamic_table.docx')
```

The result is the script add the 3 rows but no the information, why?

[Final table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dXv2u.png)

I was reading this to try and the code and template works without any problem: [Python populate a docx table with DocxTemplate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54928806/python-populate-a-docx-table-with-docxtemplate)

I aprreciate the help that I can receive.

Try to adding new information to a template table

Answer (score 0):

you have to use item['xxxx'] instead of xxxx in the template

Template
[image: template]

Output
[image: output]

Comment: Really helpfully, it works with that, tahnk you so much!